# VB.NET: Add additional functions to a class

Tags: vb.net, class, customization

the "Rectangle" class does not expose all the functions that I would need to manipulate the rectangle.
For example, I often want to change the ".Bottom" value only. 
None of the existing functions allow me to do so, and I find myself creating a new rectangle to do what I need.

This brings me to a general question:
Is it possible to add additional functions to a class in the framework that are then available in my entire project?

Comment: Yes. You can do so with extension methods.

Comment: Just to be picky, but Bottom is a value calculated adding Y and Height properties *(that's the reason for being read-only)*, how do you plan to change the Bottom of a Rectangle, modifying the Y or the Height of the Rectangle?

Comment: I see your point, and I agree with you due to how a part of it has been designed. But then again what is the use of being able to change X and Y? Or having an .Inflate method, but no overload that would allow me to inflate it only on one side instead of shrinking/expanding it and having X and Y changed along with it. To me it looks like "Yeah, let's add the most common functions/methods to Rectangle", and half the way home they noticed that they had to draw the line somewhere. And for me they drew it too early.

Comment: Can you tell me where it is stated that Bottom is to be defined as a read-only property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could

1. extend the class (like `Rectangle`) via [**extension methods**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)
2. create a custom class that holds a `Rectangle` instance(has a rectangle) and add additional properties and methods

Note that you can't inherit from `Rectangle` to extend it's functionality since it is not a `Class` but a `Structure`.

Here's a simple extension:

```
Module RectangleExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub Move(rectangle As Rectangle, x As Int32, y As Int32)
        rectangle.Location = New Point(x, y)
    End Sub

End Module
```

which you can use as if it were an existing method in `Rectangle`

```
Dim rec = New Rectangle(New Point(100, 100), New Size(50, 50))
rec.move(100, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). But there is one drawback: you can't use any private or protected member of the class this way.

On the other hand, you can try creating your own class and inherit from that one, but there are two possible drawbacks:

- you still can't use any private members from that inherited class (but can use protected ones)
- not every class from framework can be inherited - some of them are marked sealed and they cannot be inherited